# rand.randint returning same number over and over?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I'm not well versed in Python so perhaps I'm missing something obvious but I don't understand why the code I'm using to generate random numbers appears to be using the same number every cycle. I'll go through my python code below, first it some basic imports and class setup stuff:

```
import random
class Static:
# Settings (some shoudl be, you know, settings settings)
PIXEL_COUNT = 144

current_pixels = [[0,0,0]]*144
target_pixels =  [[255,255,255]]*144

# Output bar
def bar(self,settings):

    # this is where the final output pixels will go
    pixels = [(0,0,0)]*self.PIXEL_COUNT

    for pixel_index in range(self.PIXEL_COUNT):
        self.update_pixel(pixel_index)

    # Debug
    print('Update current_pixels',self.current_pixels);

    for pixel_index in range(self.PIXEL_COUNT):
        pixels[pixel_index] = (self.current_pixels[pixel_index][0],self.current_pixels[pixel_index][1],self.current_pixels[pixel_index][2])

    return pixels

# Will process the pixel and the specified index
def update_pixel(self,index):
    rand = random.randint(0,255)
    for color in range(3):
        if self.current_pixels[index][color] > self.target_pixels[index][color]:
            self.current_pixels[index][color] -= 1
        elif self.current_pixels[index][color] < self.target_pixels[index][color]:
            self.current_pixels[index][color] += 1
        else:
            self.current_pixels[index][color] = rand

_inst = Static()
bar = _inst.bar
bar({})
```

I'd be happy to put the code in a fiddle if anybody has one that isn't going to make me sign up to use it. When I run that code I get an output to the terminal of a list containing 144 lists containing the same number (all numbers across all lists are the same). As I understand the code it should have a bunch of different values (and only the values in a list pixel list should match - going for a white static thing). Like I said I'm pretty new to python so it's probably something basic but I don't have any idea what it could be. Any help?

Comment: Please write your code in one being piece with the statements between them as inline comments, right now I cannot understand the indentation of code by this format! @PhillipGooch

Answer (score 2):

your problem is your `if else` block.

```
if self.current_pixels[index][color] > self.target_pixels[index][color]:
        self.current_pixels[index][color] -= 1
elif self.current_pixels[index][color] < self.target_pixels[index][color]:
    self.current_pixels[index][color] += 1
else:
    self.current_pixels[index][color] = rand
```

This code would never reach the `else` unless the `current_pixels` element is equal to its `target_pixels` equivalent. Since every `current_pixels` element is initialized as 0, and every `target_pixels` element starts at 255, you simply trigger the `elif` block, meaning you increment all the RGB values by 1.

I'm not sure of your end goal here, but if you just wanted `current_pixels` to be initialized to random values between 0 and 255, you can do that with a nested list comprehension as a one-liner.
Just replace

```
current_pixels = [[0,0,0]]*144
```

with

```
current_pixels = [[random.randint(0,255) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(144)]
```

Comment: After the first loop through once current_pixels has been raised to target_pixels then the else should be hit and reset them to a new, random value.

Comment: After the first loop through, each pixel has only been iterated once. If you wanted the outer loop to guarantee the else was reached for all pixels, the `for pixel_index in range(self.PIXEL_COUNT):` would need to be wrapped in a `for _ in range(255):`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what that would accomplish, why would I loop through 255? I'm only looking for them all to rise is sync the first time, then for each one to be given a random value between 0-255, after which point they will all reset independently of each other (as they will hit their random value at different times).